# JSF SystemListner and dynamic user autorization setting

Tags: jsf, mojarra

I was trying to implement dynamic user access level as mentioned in [The earliest moment to visitTree() on fully built Component Tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29691625/the-earliest-moment-to-visittree-on-fully-built-component-tree) .However , I don't see the full DOM tree while parsing. While parsing I can only see the child elements of the template pages. What I'm missing?

Code snippets:

**face-config.xml**

```
<system-event-listener>
    <system-event-listener-class>com.xyz.listner.FieldDisableListener</system-event-listener-class>
    <system-event-class>javax.faces.event.PostAddToViewEvent</system-event-class>
    <source-class>javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot</source-class>
</system-event-listener>
```

**JSF Page**

```
<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/templates/samplePage.xhtml">
<ui:param name="focusElement" value="frmWelcome:newProfileLink" />
<ui:define name="pageContents">
<h:form id="pendingsearchForm" styleClass="content-body">
<h:commandLink action="#{searchBean.release}" 
                id="searchcmdbtn" <<-- updated
                value="Release" 
                immediate="true"
                rendered="#{searchBean.resultFound}" >
</h:commandLink>
```

**Listener Code**

```
@Override
public void processEvent(SystemEvent event) throws AbortProcessingException    {
UIViewRoot root = (UIViewRoot) event.getSource();
loadUserAccessConfig();
processViewTree(root);
}
@Override
public boolean isListenerForSource(Object source) {
if (source instanceof UIViewRoot)
  return true;
return false;
}
```

Comment: Your question is confusing. "full DOM tree" is impossible there. It's only available in client side (in JavaScript). I guess you actually meant "full JSF component tree". Well, which parts exactly are missing?

Comment: Thanks BalusC , yes I want to mean "Full JSF Component Tree"...as I have mentioned , the code is working fine in the landing page however while traversing to the next page by clicking on some hyperlink , the code can't parse all of the jsf component.  Updated code: <h:commandLink action="#{searchBean.release}" id="searchbtn"
                value="Release" 
                immediate="true"
                rendered="#{searchBean.resultFound}" >
</h:commandLink>

Comment: We're specifically interested in "can't". Please elaborate in technical. If you're unable to express/elaborate in correct terminology, just post a MCVE.

Comment: Here is my JSF tree parsing logic:  private void processViewTree(UIComponent component) {
  for (UIComponent child : component.getChildren()) {
   logger.debug("child retrived " + child.getId() + " class " + child.getClass());
   processViewTree(child);
  }
 }  and the child getid() is not retrieving  "searchcmdbtn".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the following change in my JSF tree parsing logic to make my code work:

```
facesContext.getViewRoot().getFacetsAndChildren();
```